# Docker with Node and Vue cannot bring up a running server

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:current-buster

# Utilities: System
RUN apt update && apt install -y nano apt-utils
#RUN npm install -g @vue/cli-service-global

# Utilities: Node & Vue
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ls -al
```

And my docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: "3"
services:

  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: 'vuejs-webserver'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
      - "80:8080"
      - "81:8081"
      - "82:8082"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

In my local folder, /app contains a Vue project. At the time Docker is building the container, there is nothing in /app, therefore I cannot run `npm run serve` to start my Vue application. Once the container has been build, I can `docker exec -it vuejs-webserver bash` and run `npm run serve`, because now the /app folder has been filled.

How can I build a Dockerfile to run my server automatically?

Comment: What's the point of downvoting my question? If I've missed something I'd like to know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `COPY` command in Dockerfile to copy your code into container while it is building and `RUN` command to run your project in container on startup

Answer (score 0):

> At the time Docker is building the container, there is nothing in
> /app,

But still, you can specify the `CMD` as it helps you start your application once you run `docker-compose up` with bind host volumes.

```
WORKDIR /app
RUN ls -al
CMD ["npm","run","serve"]
```

Or You will have to set the  `command` in the docker-compose file.

```
version: "3"
services:

  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: 'vuejs-webserver'
    restart: 'always'
    command: npm run serve
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
      - "80:8080"
      - "81:8081"
      - "82:8082"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I've voted the vengleab as accepted answer because he/she wrote it first. I have an extra question that would make me change the accepted answer to you: Why CMD ["npm","run","serve"] works right after 'ls -al' showed nothing? Isn't true that Node needs a *.json file where it specifies 'serve' script?

Comment: its worked becuase it get code during docker-compose up, if you run with `docker run -it --rm my_image` it will not work because there will be no code